# Alternative to -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 in find

Tags: find

I often find myself using `find` to search just the 1st generation children of a directory, especially in scripts to replace `*`. Is there a more convenient way to do this than to specify `-maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1`?

Is there another tool I should use?

Comment: What is an example of a script where you can't just use `*`?

Comment: @Sparhawk Apart from not usually matching hidden names, and not being able to do any other tests on the pathnames as part of the expansion (as with e.g. `-type f` or `-user myself`), there is no difference.

Comment: @Kusalananda I was wondering which aspect of `find` was specifically required by the questioner. roaima's answer makes the assumption that dotfiles are the difference, but this isn't clear from the question at all.

Comment: @Commodore64 `find . ! -name . -prune` is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a shell such as `bash` you can set the `dotglob` shell option to have the asterisk wildcard `*` match ALL files rather than just those that don't start with a dot `.` character.

For any given directory these three examples should all return the same set of files

*example 1*

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf '%f\n'
```

*example 2*

```
dg=$(shopt -q dotglob)
shopt -s dotglob
echo *
[[ $dg -eq 1 ]] && shopt -u dotglob
```

*example 3*

```
( shopt -s dotglob; echo * )
```